# How to reduce the length of the string to 10 words in R?

Tags: r, csv

I have a csv file like

```
Identity,Keyword
23, The weather is perfect for good days football the players are healthy
45,  1 Locksmith services Locally Owned and Operated Fast response time Call Now
```

I want to reduce the number of words in the column Keyword to 10

Desired output

```
Identity,Keyword
23, The weather is perfect for good days football the players 
45,  1 Locksmith services Locally Owned and Operated Fast response time
```

I am using the code

```
keyword <- sapply(record$Keyword,function(x) gsub("^((\\w+\\W+){9}\\w+).*","\\1",x))
```

It is not reducing the number of words to 10 for the second identity. What is going wrong? Any help is appreciated?

Comment: Your sapply code works for me.

Comment: Possibly a problem with leading/trailing space in the second keyword. Try running `record$Keyword <- gsub( "^ +| +$" , "" , record$Keyword )` first and then your `sapply` approach (which is nice by the way! +1, its far better than my *answer*)

Comment: Are you expecting the "1" to not match as a word? ?regex explains that \w matches alphas and numbers.

Comment: @Spacedman I want to match "1" as a word

Comment: I tried this again and realized I missed the space before the one in your second identity. Look @SimonO'Hanlon's comment above or answer below to strip the leading spaces first and then your code should work

Comment: @infominer I have exactly done that and it has worked, for me just removed the trailing and the header spaces and then I have used sapply

Comment: agreed with @infominer http://stackoverflow.com/users/2747709/infominer & @Simon http://stackoverflow.com/users/1478381/simon-ohanlon, your code works and rly just needs that space removal. Your `sapply()` also preserves multiple spaces within the phrases so adding a `record$Keyword <- gsub("\ +", " ", record$Keyword)` might also be good if you want to force single spaces between the keywords.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the benefit of others giving a different answer I've added your data in a copy/paste format...

```
# The data....
df <- read.table( text = "Identity,Keyword
23, \'The weather is perfect for good days football the players are healthy\'
45,  \'1 Locksmith services Locally Owned and Operated Fast response time Call Now\'" , header = TRUE , sep = "," , stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Strip out leading and trailing spaces (which were a problem for me)
df$Keyword <- gsub( "^ +| +$" , "" , df$Keyword )

# Split words on spaces, and select the first 10 elements of each
ll <- lapply( strsplit( df$Keyword , " " ) , `[` , 1:10 )

# Collapse to a single 10 word string and add to the orginal data.frame
df$Short <- sapply( ll , paste , collapse = " " )

#  Identity                                                                     Keyword                                                              Short
#1       23       The weather is perfect for good days football the players are healthy          The weather is perfect for good days football the players
#2       45 1 Locksmith services Locally Owned and Operated Fast response time Call Now 1 Locksmith services Locally Owned and Operated Fast response time
```

Comment: Does subsetting the first ten elements with `1:10` work well for strings less than 10 words long?

Comment: @BenBarnes yeah fair point. This is a totally rubbish answer. +1 for Martin I say.

Comment: Well, just do it in more steps: first do the strsplit, then extract `foo<- bar[1:(min(length(bar),10)]`

Comment: No need to do rest of the steps just removing the spaces and then applying the same code I have used works fine for me

Comment: Subsetting `x[-(11:1000000)]` will return the first up-to-ten elements as long as `x` is less than a million long, unlike `x[1:10]` which will pad short `x`s with `NA`. Of course you are generating a sequence of approx length 999989 which you are mostly throwing away...